ExtractValuestoPoints reorganizes the FID from each iteration
I have a shapefile that defines a line with 10,000 points.
I am iterating over a set of rasters and extracting the raster value on these same points for each raster. The output feature dataset it creates still has 10,000 points but they are reorganized. For instance, the last point in the input shapefile was FID=10,000 but but one iteration the last point is 8455 and for the another it is 9,450.
The output still has 10,000 points but seem to be in a different order than the input points. I thought maybe this was due to null values but I have tried to also output to a dataframe (via in_memory instead of an output shapefile) but I get 10,000 values but clearly the raster values are not aligned spatially due to the re-ordering. The rasters are all different extents (e.g., not covering the full set of points on the line). Is there something wrong with the call below?
ExtractValuesToPoints(input_shapefile, inRaster, output_shapefile, "INTERPOLATE", "VALUE_ONLY")
#or alternately:
ExtractValuesToPoints(input_shapefile, inRaster, "in_memory/values", "INTERPOLATE", "ALL")
points_df = pd.DataFrame(arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("in_memory/values",["RASTERVALU"],skip_nulls=False, null_value=-9999))
dfz[f'raster_value_{j + 1}'] = points_df['RASTERVALU']


How are you iterating over your rasters, that seems important yet you don't describe what you have done. You don't even say what software you are using. I've replicated your scenario with a couple of partially overlapping rasters, so different extents and running the ExtractValuesToPoints directly it kept the order of the points I had created. So it work for me. I was using ArcPro 3.4
